# How to get jumbotron colour to also cover navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a picture (below I've tested with a single background color) to cover the navbar aswell as the showcase/jumbotron.  However I can't get it to cover both correctly and the navbar is left untouched - even if I create a div that surround the navbar and jumbotron and assign a background picture to this.

Additionally when I try a picture it is stretched in a rather random way across the showcase, how do I get this to cover the elements correctly ?(image size is 1400x693 svg).

```
<header class="nav-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#"><span class="navbar-brand"><i>Logo</i></span></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"
              aria-controls="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">How it works</a></li>
        </ul><!--//nav-->

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">Log out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav><!--//header-->
</header>

<section>
  <div class="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid showcase-content text-white">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h2 class="display-4">Some title.</h2>
            <p class="lead">Some additional showcase text.</p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary text-white " href="#">Get Started -></a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <image></image>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--//container-->
  </div>
</section><!--//promo-->
```

Css

```
.showcase {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nav-header {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.showcase-content {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjqvEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was having bg-light within the navbar which was overriding assigning the colour to the navbar too.